# What is the ^= operator?

Tags: java, operators, bitwise-operators

I just came across an answer here on SO where a code example (in what I thought was java) used an operator I have never seen before: `^=`. I searched google and SO and haven't been able to find it anywhere else and when I tried to test it out using java, eclipse went crazy. Maybe it was just a typo in the answer, I'm not sure. What is this operator? Does it have a name? What language is it from or used in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the C/C++/C#/Java/Javascript/Perl/PHP/Pike bitwise XOR assignment operator.

An XOR (exclusive or) conditional statement evaluates to true *if and only if* one of the two operands involved is true.

**Example:**

```
0 ^ 0 = false
1 ^ 0 = true
0 ^ 1 = true
1 ^ 1 = false //Regular OR would evaluate this as true
```

In the same way that you can use `+=` `-=` `*=` `/=` etc... this operator can be combined with an equals sign to perform assignment upon completion.

```
x += 1; //Same as x = x + 1;
t ^= f; //Same as t = t ^ f;

boolean a = false;
boolean b = true;
a ^= b; //a now evaluates to true;
```

See [Java Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

Answer (score 9):

It is the C/C++/C#/Java/Javascript/Perl bitwise xor assignment operator.

Answer (score 2):

It would depend on the language, but ^ is typically an exclusive-or (example languages: java, c-family); a ^= b is shorthand for a = a^b.

Comment: @csmckelvey Look att http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xor The truth-table: 0 ^ 0 = 0, 0 ^ 1 = 1, 1 ^ 0 = 1, 1 ^ 1 = 0

Answer (score 2):

take a look here

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html
 and
 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

but it is a  Bitwise Exclusive or with assignment

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery it means "starting with this"

For example
    id^='my_'

means "id starts with 'my_'"

Comment: Why write an answer about jQuery if the question is about Java? (see tags)

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa At the time when this answer was written, there where no tag about java, only `operators`.

Comment: Yep, the text still ends like "What language is it from or used in?"

Answer (score 0):

In the php manual it says that ^ is the bitwise XOR operator.
Here's the [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)