# what is '^=' operator in java

Tags: java, bitwise-xor

My code is as following:

```
char ch = t.charAt(t.length() - 1);
        // result of XOR of two char is Integer.
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
            ch = ch^s.charAt(i);
            ch = ch^t.charAt(i);
        }

        return ch;
```

it throws error

> Line 6: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to char
>               ch = ch^s.charAt(i);
>
> Line 7: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to char
>               ch = ch^t.charAt(i);
>
> 2 errors

However, When I change

```
ch = ch^s.charAt(i);
ch = ch^t.charAt(i);
```

to

```
ch ^= s.charAt(i);
ch ^= t.charAt(i);
```

Then, my code can work.

Are '^=' and '* = *^*' different?? Why I search this question about '^=', it says they are same??

[What is the '^=' operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20793452/what-is-the-operator)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the functionality, they are the same: both perform an exclusive OR.

But the data types are different:

- if I do `x = x ^ y`, the data type of `x ^ y` is always `int` or greater. When the result is assigned to something smaller, you have to cast.
- if I do `x ^= y`, the data type doesn't grow as the assignment "knows its type".

  See the language specification at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2 for more details.

Comment: Question: is this the same as doing `int x; int y;` and  `x = x / y;` vs `x /= y;` You don't know if the value is gonna be a decimal-one (and get truncated) or an integer (*based on the inputted values*)? eg. `x = 3, y = 2`.

Comment: @Joel With integers, the result is always integer. If you want to avoid that, you have to multiply with 1.0 befre the division (or to add 0.0), or to cast.

Comment: yes, it will be truncated as i mentioned in my question. But, i'm wondering if the concept is the same? it forces the type of LH-value?

Comment: @Joel Yes. I added a link to the relevant part of the Java Language Specification.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `ch` to be an `int`, or store the result of the bitwise xor `^=` in an `int` field. Right now it's trying to store it in a `char` which is where the error is coming from.