# What does ^= mean in Java for-loops?

Tags: java, for-loop

I came across this line of code

```
for (int i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) num ^= nums[i]
```

What does `^=` mean?

Comment: [Bitwise xor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) means the same thing outside a loop. `num = num ^ nums[i]`. See also [XOR gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_gate) Wikipedia entry.

Answer (score 0):

It is the bitwise XOR operator. 
Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20793452/what-is-the-operator) answer for a more in depth explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bitwise XOR operator normally used for """encryption""" it works like this:

```
A|B|Y
0|0|0
0|1|1
1|0|1
1|1|0
```

here is an example:

```
a ^ z
'a' in binary is 01100001 
'z' in binary is 01111010 
01100001 
01111010
00011011 = 27(ESC in ASCII)
```